# Android Pick Image Always in Portrait mode?

Tags: android

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        startActivityForResult(i,0);
```

but this always displays the picker in portrait mode. Is there a way to make that landscape?
thanks!

Comment: You could check how this intent receiver consumes the intent. May be it will give u a clue as to how to make it landscape.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried this on `HTC Desire (2.2)` now without a problem.

Can you pls. tell us your device model & firmware?

Additionally, when calling the Pick intent, your source activity has no restriction on orientation, right? I.e., there is no

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

set in your AndroidManifest.xml, correct?